# A simple way to make crushed ice?

Tags: freezing

For many of my favourite cold drinks I need crushed ice. That is, thousands of small pieces of ice, not 3 big ice cubes. Is there an easy way to make crushed ice without expensive equipment?

Comment: Does a blender count as expensive equipment?  That's probably the easiest option if you have one available to use.

Comment: With sharon stone: http://bloodysox.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/sharon-ice-pick-stone.jpg?w=224&h=224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried [this method](http://web.archive.org/web/20091031184109/http://www.ehow.com/how_5053569_make-easy-crushed-ice.html) myself, but it sounds reasonable.

It involves filling a clean milk carton or juice container with water, freezing it and then bashing it against a wall to crush the ice. I guess the container has to be quite sturdy to take the beating without breaking. Could be worth a try.

Comment: How often do you get to bash something against concrete while you're preparing food or drink? Awesome.

Comment: So true. This will rock regardless of whether it works or not. :) EDIT: The "rock" pun is unintentional.

Answer (score 10):

Put ice cubes in a clean tea towel and bash them with a rolling pin works for me.

Comment: Seems to me like this good for the rolling pin, especially not the bearings.

Comment: @Zanlok -- not all rolling pins have bearings. But if you're worried, you can substitute with a hammer or meat tenderizer.

Comment: Ah, now a menacing meat tenderizer would be fun, indeed =).

Comment: even just bashing against the work surface works. @Zanlok I'd forgotten some rolling pins are more complex than others you're right that some could get damaged. Mine are heavy wooden or plastic tubes with or without fixed handles.

Comment: I have done this in high school - we needed a boatload of crushed ice for thermodynamics experiments. It works, but notice that the tea towel will never be the same. If you apply enough enthusiasm to the job, you can actually get holes.

Comment: bashing the pack of towel with ice on a cemented floor might also work.

Answer (score 9):

Hammer and bag?  That's how I've always done it.

Answer (score 1):

i picked up an old-style ice crusher at a thrift store, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use that mixer/slicer combo for it.
Such device is often used to slice fruits, or even meat in tiny pieces, you just do short bursts of knives, like 2 seconds and then see if its tiny enough.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "[Snow Cone Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030V7BZI)" at Amazon.com. The one I linked to is $20.00 (US), does that qualify as "expensive"? Granted, shipping to Cape Town may be a bit higher, but you should be able to find something closer to you than Cleveland, USA. However, at the current exchange rate something in The US might be cheaper for you...

Answer (score -1):

Put the ice cubes in your hand or towel (whichever you prefer) and bash it with the back of a big or medium spoon.

Comment: You might share what sort of ice cubes you have. Cubes from automatic ice makers may break more easily than cubes from an ice tray.